# property of functions satisfying the inverse function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, inverse-function-theorem

Let f be a function from R^m onto the same.if it is continuously differentiable around a neighbourhood of a, and  a has a non singular derivative, then so do all points  in some neighbourhood of a.

Is the above statement true? I have been unable to find this in any textbook. this question is motivated by the inverse function theorem since proving this will make a proof of that very simple.

Comment: The function $\det\circ Df:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R$ is continuous since $Df$ and $\det$ are. And since $f$ is non-singular at $x_0$ by hypothesis, $\det\circ Df(x_0)\neq 0$ so....

Comment: my way of proving it was that Df(x)*h/|h| has a lower bound a>0, |(Df(t)-Df(x))*h/|h|| has a upper bound b in that open set U(t belongs to U). setting b<a proves the theorem .Am I correct?